# Android gamedev advice

Tags: android

I'm planning to develop a simple tic-tac-toe 3D game for android as a starting point (practical task to learn and do something useful), but [devguid](http://developer.android.com/) seems to be more of a reference than something with what I can get my hands on particular task. Can someone advice what should be investigated? (or maybe I'm searching for it incorrectly)

EDIT: I'm also considering other options on learning android development. (Though, the "practice while learning" approach is preferred).

**EDIT:**

My purpose: learn how to develop apps for android && create an app, which is fun and can be placed on android market

My initial "data": strong java + java ee, basic C/C++, willing to learn

Means to achieve purpose: [devguide](http://developer.android.com/) is more of a reference, and I need a solid start with lots of explanations. Need an advice here.

Comment: You should refine your request. Do you want advice on game design? On Android development? On Java? On mobile development? On tic-tac-toe strategies? Something else? I'd recommend just jumping in (maybe with the Android tutorials and samples) and posting for help when and if you get stuck on something in particular.

Comment: @Ted Hopp, Isn't "a simple tic-tac-toe 3D game for android as a starting point (practical task to learn and do something useful)" enough?

Comment: Not really. What is your specific question? How to design the interface? How to handle the game logic? How to program the AI for a computer opponent?

Comment: Your choice of application is a great starting point, and "practice while learning" is also a great approach. The problem, as @kcoppock also points out, is that, "Can someone advice what should be investigated?" is way too vague and general a question.

Comment: @all, thanks guys, I guess I found the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out several tutorials [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial), especially testing ones. Get your hands on [Pro Android Games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430226471) with reading [devguide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) when some part of android development is unknown.

This will result in a rapid development (with a zero level starting point) and small learning curve of basic + in deep android development.

Answer (score 0):

You see, to my mind there is no sense to read books and so on. First reading starting manuals from Google should definately help. When you are done with them you should jump into development. Of course, you will have a lot of questions, however there are lots of great manuals and tutorials all over the internet, so you will rarely have difficulties. If you even though have them, come here and we'll help =) Check out my [devBlog](http://knightswhocode.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple tic tac toe for my first Android application and I was able to create a working game quite quickly using a table of image views. You just need to add clickHandler events onto the image views so they change image on click, and write a function checking whether the game is won after the click.